# Numbers such that $ \sqrt{ {a_{1}}^{a_{2}^{...^{a_{n}}}}} = a_{1} a_{2} \dots a_{n}$

Tags: reference-request, exponentiation, power-towers

I wonder whether there are any resources on the equation:

$$\require{\MnSymbol} \require{\mathdots} \sqrt{  {a_{1}}^{a_{2}^{...^{a_{n}}}}} = a_{1} a_{2} \dots a_{n}. \tag{1}$$

Here, $a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots, a_{n} \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$, and the power tower on the left should have $n$ terms as well -- I wasn't entirely sure how to format it (including the diagonal dots from lower left to the upper right corner) in MathJax. The terms on the right denote a the digits of a single number in base ten.

I found an example of such an identity [over here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-screenshot-that-deserves-89-000-million-upvotes/answer/Avinash-Sharma-1438?ch=17&oid=1477743702140231&share=011d7136&srid=uqC8&target_type=answer):

$$ \sqrt{ {{{{{{2}^{6}}^{2}}^{1}}^{4}}^{4}} } = 262144. \tag{2} $$

> **Questions**:
>
> 1. Are there any resources on equations of the form $(1)$ ?
> 2. Can you find any solutions, besides the one described in $(2)$? I'm especially interested in solutions that don't involve the number one -- it feels a bit like cheating in the left side of the equation.

Comment: You can ask Mathinity (on instagram). He was the one who discovered the identity.

Comment: The sequence $(a_n)_n = (26, 84, 6, 0, 31393932323010374318061912785738337881638804914176)$ is another example :) You can split the last bit up however you want. The $0$ is still cheating a bit.
I found it by writing a little Python program. My main observation is you
can work out if $(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$ trivially extends (by cheating)
to a valid sequence by working out the square root of the power tower, checking $a_1 \dotsm a_m$ is a prefix and checking the rest starts with a $1$
or contains a $0$ somewhere. I haven't found an example other than this and your
one - $(2, 6, 2, 144)$.

Comment: I have some examples in base $2$. They all cheat. I'm taking $0^0$ to be $1$. Here they are:
$(110,110,0,0)$,
$(1001,1001,1,100011)$,
$(10111,110,0,0,0,111)$,
$(1000001100,111110,10,0,10110111...)$,
$(11001,11011,0,0,1011100011...)$,
$(1010,10,1001,1,1111011101...)$,
$(101,1000,101,0,0,1000010101...)$,
$(111010,10010,11,1,0,0,0,0,100000...)$,
$(1001000000,10011,10,10,1,0,0,0,0,0,110...)$,
$(110,10,11,10,1,0,101000100...)$.
Some of the numbers are very long.
If you allow leading zeroes, there's
$(1110100,11110,01,0,1000001100...)$,
$(110111,1010,100,01111,0,0100100010...)$,

Answer (score 3):

Regarding question 2, there are no solutions with every $a_i>1$. The rapid growth of power towers allows for an exhaustive search within some easily bounded parameters. Here's a summary of "near solutions", those with a left side that evaluates to an integer with the correct number of digits:

It's not possible with for $n\geq 5$, since $\sqrt{2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}} > 10^{9864}$.

If $n=4$, the only expression with the correct number of digits is $\sqrt{3^{2^{2^2}}} = 6561$.

If $n=3$, the only expressions with the correct number of digits are $\sqrt{k^{2^2}}$ for $32 \leq k \leq 316$; $\sqrt{4^{3^2}} = 512$; $\sqrt{2^{4^2}} = 256$; $\sqrt{4^{2^3}} = 256$; $\sqrt{5^{2^3}} = 625$; and $\sqrt{2^{2^4}} = 256$.

A solution with $\sqrt{k^{2^2}}$ would satisfy $k^2 = 100k + 22$, which has no integer roots.

If $n=2$, the only expressions with the correct number of digits are $\sqrt{k^3}$ for $k = j^2$ with $j=3$, $5\leq j \leq 21$, or $32 \leq j \leq 46$; $\sqrt{k^4}$ for $4 \leq k \leq 31$; $\sqrt{4^5} = 32$; $\sqrt{3^6} = 27$; $\sqrt{4^6} = 64$; $\sqrt{2^8} = 16$; $\sqrt{3^8} = 81$; $\sqrt{3^{10}} = 243$; $\sqrt{3^{12}} = 729$; $\sqrt{2^{14}} = 128$; $\sqrt{2^{16}} = 256$; and $\sqrt{2^{18}} = 512$.

A solution with $\sqrt{k^3}$ for $k = j^2$ would satisfy $j^3 = 10j^2 + 3$, which has no integer roots.

A solution with $\sqrt{k^4}$ would satisfy $k^2 = 10k + 4$, which has no integer roots.

Comment: Perhaps solutions exist in a base other than 10.